# HtmlHelper for model array value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, html-helper

I'm trying to bind a list of CheckBoxes to a member of my model which happens to be an array. I used:

```
for (int i=0; i< ARRAYLENGTH; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.myArray[i])
}
```

but it generated a 'collection is read-only' error when attempting to bind. So is it even possible to use the CheckBoxFor helper to render a checkbox for an individual array element (which is a member of the model)?

Comment: do you have both getter and setter for myArray collection ?

Comment: Yes, using C#: public bool myArray { get; set; }

Comment: Somehow your myArray is readonly. Can you show the definition of it ?

Comment: If your myArray has type bool, it is not array (may be you lost []).

Comment: Sorry, I left out the brackets in my post above. It is a true array. I was able to eliminate the error message today by changing the array from a public _property_ to a public _variable_. Don't know why that made a difference. My new problem: the values of the checkboxes do not get passed to the controller when the page posts...weird because all the other model-bound values (textboxes mainly) on the page are passed via the model to the controller as they should be. Anyone know why these "CheckBoxFors" aren't posting their model values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) MVC framework uses by default `DefaultModelBinder` class to construct a model from posted values. When binding a collection, it uses `ICollection<T>` interface and calls `Clear()` method before filling the collection with posted values. Then, `Add()` method is called.

Since you have an array, `Clear()` method does not actually clear anything('cause arrays are of fixed size), but replaces array values with default values(0 for numerics, false for booleans, null for reference types).

For the same reason(array's fixed size) `Add()` method causes an error.

2) `DefaultModelBinder` works with **properties**, not fields. That's why the values are not bound after you made the array a public field.

The solution is to change your property's type from array to `IList<YourType>` or `List<YourType>`. `IList<T>` allows you to use [] syntax in views as well.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.